# Extending or composing Pinia setup stores for reusable getters, setters and actions

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, state, store, pinia

Imagine we have a Pinia setup store that implements a basic set of state, getters and actions:

```
export const useBaseStore = defineStore('base-store', () => {
  const name = ref<string>('');
  const age = ref<number>(1);
  const ageString = computed(() => `${name.value} is aged ${size.value}`)

  function doubleAge() {
    age.value *= 2;
  }

  return { name, age, ageString, doubleAge }
}
```

How can we extend or compose this store into further stores to reuse this set of state behaviours? For example

```
export const usePersonStore = defineStore('person-store', () => {

  // ... somehow compose all of 'base-store'

  function tripleAge() {
    age.value *= 3;
  }

  return {
    // ...include all getters, setters and actions returned by 'base-store', as well as those defined here
    tripleAge
  }
}

export const useOtherStore = defineStore('other-store', () => {

  // ... somehow compose all of 'base-store'

  function sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello')
  }

  return {
    // ...include all getters, setters and actions returned by 'base-store', as well as those defined here
    sayHello
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Composing Pinia can be done a few ways. Rather than trying to extend a store, I created a composable out of your base store, and then defined two stores from that.

The *person-store* needs access to `age` from within the `tripleAge()` function, so the setup is bringing in the base as a constant.

The *other-store* just directly uses a spread operator because it only adds one new function, and doesn't need access to the other properties/functions.

```
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

const useBaseStore = () => {
  const name = ref<string>('');
  const age = ref<number>(1);
  const ageString = computed(() => `${name.value} is aged ${age.value}`);

  function doubleAge() {
    age.value *= 2;
  }

  return { name, age, ageString, doubleAge };
};

export const usePersonStore = defineStore('person-store', () => {
  const base = useBaseStore();
  function tripleAge() {
    base.age.value *= 3;
  }
  return { ...base, tripleAge };
});

export const useOtherStore = defineStore('other-store', () => {
  function sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello');
  }
  return {
    ...useBaseStore(),
    sayHello,
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do with store options as this doesn't require to keep the references to base data in order to access it; it's available on store instance:

```
function defineFooStore(name, options = {}) {
  return defineStore(name, {
    state: () => ({
      foo: 1,
      ...options.state
    }),
    actions: {
      doFoo() {},
      ...options.actions
    },
    getters: {
      getFoo() {},
      ...options.actions
    },
  });
}
```

On the other hand, it will require more work to be properly typed as generic function in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, not 100% sure if it's the best way but it works for me:

The base store that needs to be extended:

```
// file stores/entity.js

export const entityStore = {
    state: () => ({
        stateA: ...,
        stateB: ...,
    }),
    getters: {
        getter1: ...,
        getter2: ...,
    },
    actions: {
        actionX() {
            ...
        },
        actionY() {
            ...
        },
    }
}
```

An example Users store that extends the base store:

```
// file stores/users.js

import {entityStore} from "./entity";
import {defineStore} from "pinia";

export const useUsersStore = defineStore('users', {
        state: () => ({
            ...entityStore.state(),
            stateC: ...
        }),
        getters: {
            ...entityStore.getters,
            getter3: ...,
        },
        actions: {
            ...entityStore.actions,
            actionZ() {
               ...
            }
        },
    })
```