# Inherit / Merge Pinia Stores

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I am creating Pinia stores and would like to have a base store and 2 child stores:

```
Base
- ChildA
- ChildB
```

Properties, for example, would be something like:

```
Base
 > state:
    - name
    - make
    - model
 > getters:
    - makeAndModel (state.make + state.model)
 > actions:
    - printMakeAndModel()

ChildA (inherit from Base)
 > state:
    - color
 > actions:
    - getYearModelFromColor(color)

ChildB (inherit from Base)
 > state:
    - color
 > actions:
    - getYearModelFromColor(color)
```

So what I wanted to do is be able to call the Base Store's properties (state, action, getters) from the Vue file

Example:

```js
const childAStore = useChildAStore()
const childBStore = useChildBStore()

const sampleStore = (someCondition) ? childAStore : childBStore 
console.log(sampleStore.getYearModelFromColor()) // action from childA/B
console.log(sampleStore.printMakeAndModel()) // action from Base
console.log(sampleStore.color) // state from childA/B
console.log(sampleStore.make) // action from childA/B
```

I am thinking of calling useBaseStore() inside the children stores, this would allow the children stores to access Base store's properties, but I'm not sure how to expose it to the Vue caller.

How can I do these in Pinia?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76931996/3731501